# RoR live search

Tags: ruby-on-rails

iam doing live search function,

for this iam using observer_field, but on pageload i get error

jquery('#name').delayedObserver is not a function

I dont know what is the problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

js libraries weren't loading in the proper order. If you are having this problem it would be a good strategy to take out all of your other libraries an simply load these to see if it fixes the problem. Once you have it working, add them back in until you have it working in the proper order.

```
script src = "/javascripts/jquery.js" type = "text/javascript">
script src = "/javascripts/jquery-ui.js" type = "text/javascript">
script src = "/javascripts/jrails.js" type = "text/javascript">
```